# Replacing multiple CHR() from PLSQL string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PLSQL string which contains chr() special characters like chr(10), chr(13). I want to replace these special characters from the string. I tried the following ways

```
select  regexp_replace('Hello chr(10)Goodchr(13)Morning','CHR(10)|chr(13)','') from dual;
```

This do not works since regexp_replace do not replace chr() function. Then I tried

```
select translate('Hello chr(10)Goodchr(13)Morning', 'chr(10)'||'chr(13)', ' ') from dual;
```

It works partially, ie; I am forced to replace chr() with white space(third parameter). No option if I do not want to replace chr() with white spaces . If I pass third character as null then above query returns null result.
Anybody have any other methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your replacement isn't the logic, it's the syntax.  Parentheses are regex metacharacters, and as such, if you want to replace a literal parenthesis, you need to escape it.  So your pattern should be this:

```
chr\(13\)|chr\(10\)
```

Here is a working query:

```
select
    regexp_replace('Hello chr(10)Goodchr(13)Morning','chr\(13\)|chr\(10\)','', 1, 0, 'i')
from dual
```

The fifth parameters in the above call to `regexp_replace` is `'i'` and indicates that we want to do a case insensitive replacement.

### Demo

The above logic removes the *literal* text `chr(13)` and `chr(10)` from your text.  If instead you want to remove the actual control characters `chr(13)` and `chr(10)`, then you may add those control characters to the alternation, e.g.

```
select
    regexp_replace('Hello chr(10)Goodchr(13)Morning','chr\(13\)|chr\(10\)|chr(10)|chr(13)','', 1, 0, 'i')
from dual
```

Comment: Hi sir this works, But I tried another string  and that does not works . It produces a new line. see here  http://rextester.com/VRS91067

Comment: You've changed the question.  Your question was about removing the _literal_ text `chr(10)` and `chr(13)`.  Your sample data includes actual newlines/carriage returns, so of course they are still appearing in the output.

Comment: Should I ask it as another question?

Comment: @Nidheesh Just add `chr(10)` and `chr(13)` to the regex alternation, and this time _don't_ escape the parentheses, because you mean the actual control character.  [See here](http://rextester.com/RXAKB24175) for your updated demo.  By the way, I find it strange that you are trying to find literal `chr(10)` in your text.

Answer (score 1):

Since regular expression functions are relatively expensive in Oracle I think it's worth showing the alternate method which just uses REPLACE for the same effect.
This replaces occurrences of the each control characters with a space;

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('ABC'||CHR(10)||'DEF'||CHR(13)||'GHI'||CHR(10)||'JKL',CHR(13),' '),CHR(10),' ') from dual
```

And this replaces occurrences of the strings 'CHR(13)' and 'CHR(10)';

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE('ABCCHR(10)DEFCHR(13)GHICHR(10)JKL','CHR(13)',' '),'CHR(10)',' ') from dual
```